# TeamCity getting fxcop and coveragereport into build artifacts via artifact paths

Tags: teamcity

i'm trying to get the fxCop result xml and coveragereport.xml to publish to the artifacts after build.

the following is what I have now,

```
%system.teamcity.build.tempDir%/fxcop-output*/fxcop-result.xml => BuildLog/FxCop
%system.teamcity.build.tempDir%/teamcity*ncover/CoverageReport.xml => BuildLog/Coverage
```

but the result directory has the following format

```
BuildLog --> Coverage --> teamcity8681981431807223307ncover --> CoverageReport.xml
BuildLog --> FxCop --> fxcop-output-3810116228914218788 --> fxcop-result.xml
```

I am curious what should I do to make it like the following without the containing folder structure.

```
BuildLog --> Coverage --> CoverageReport.xml
BuildLog --> FxCop --> fxcop-result.xml
```

thanks

Answer (score 4):

Because there is an asterisk (*) in the artifact source definition, there could be more than one source file grabbed by the search pattern.

To differenciate these (theoretically multiple) files in the output path, TeamCity will add the match for the * - pattern in the output structure, e.g. [...]teamcity **8681981431807223307** ncover[...]. Therefore it is impossible to select (potentially) multiple files and store them as one file.

Perhaps a different approach is the answer. You could write a MSBuild script that uses the [TeamCity Build Script Interaction feature](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD65/Build+Script+Interaction+with+TeamCity#BuildScriptInteractionwithTeamCity-PublishingArtifactswhiletheBuildisStillinProgress), similar to this:

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" 
     ToolsVersion="4.0">

<ItemGroup>
  <FxCopResults Include="%system.teamcity.build.tempDir%/fxcop-output*/fxcop-result.xml" />
  <CoverageResults Include="%system.teamcity.build.tempDir%/teamcity*ncover/CoverageReport.xml" />
</ItemGroup>

<Target Name="PublishArtifacts">
  <Message Text="##teamCity[publishArtifacts '%(FxCopResults) => BuildLog\FxCop'" />
  <Message Text="##teamCity[publishArtifacts '%(CoverageResults) => BuildLog\Coverage'" />
</Target>
```

Finally, a TeamCity Build Step with the MSBuild build runner could be used to start the msbuild target "PublishArtifacts" in this script after the analysis build steps were performed.